# после установки webpack появилась утечка памяти react useeffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

1. Вот ошибка: VM431 bundle.js:12325 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on
   an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory
   leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and
   asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function
2. Все страницы в router-dom при переходе показывают Не удается получить доступ к сайтуСайт localhost не позволяет установить соединение.
3. При нажатий на кнопки ничего не происходит при том что запрос с app.js выводит в консоль результат

Вопрос как найти утечку памяти в этом приложений приложение большое это как искать иголку в стоге сена и вообще что с этим делать заказчик угрожает говорит прострелит коленку помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Привет. Искать иголку в стоге сена не нужно. Надо посмотреть какие компоненты размонтирует компонент, действия которого вызывают утечку памяти и просто закоментировать их по одному, пока не найдешь нужный. После того, как компонент будет найден необходимо искать причину этого

Comment: А сама утечка памяти имеет место? Просто _Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component_ может просто означать, что вы пытаетесь изменить состояние компонента из асинхронной функции, которая выполняется, когда компонент уже размонтировался. Например запустили таймаут, который должен через N секунд скрыть надпись, а за это время перешли на страницу с другим компонентом. Таймаут сработает вовремя, но изменять состояние уже не у чего